# How to use Prolog with PHP?

Tags: php, prolog

I want to use Prolog with PHP. Is it possible?

Comment: "Use" in what way? Please elaborate.

Comment: to run Prolog programs in PHP, ex. solving Einstein's riddle http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always the [exec-familiy](http://uk.php.net/exec) functions to execute/spawn another process.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, you can execute a Prolog interpreter or binary. However, most Prolog implementations also export a C API that can be used to call the Prolog interpreter.

You could create a small PHP module to start an interpreter and execute queries. For instance, the SICStus documentation describes using Prolog from C in detail:

- [6 Mixing C/C++ and Prolog](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Mixing-C-and-Prolog.html#Mixing-C-and-Prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Most Prologs allow for prolog code to be compiled into a binary. You could try calling this binary from within PHP using some kind of process call as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a translator](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22function%20is_greater_than(%24a%2C%24b)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20%24a%20%3E%20%24b%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cnfunction%20is_an_animal(%24a)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20in_array(%24a%2C%5B%5C%22dog%5C%22%2C%5C%22cat%5C%22%5D)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22php%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22prolog%22%7D) that can convert some simple PHP programs into Prolog and [vice-versa](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cnis_greater_than(A%2CB)%20%3A-%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20A%3EB.%20%5Cnis_an_animal(A)%20%3A-%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20member(A%2C%5B%5C%22dog%5C%22%2C%5C%22cat%5C%22%5D).%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22prolog%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22php%22%7D).

This is a possible input program:

```
function is_greater_than($a,$b){
    return $a > $b;
}
function is_an_animal($a){
    return in_array($a,["dog","cat"]);
}
```

...and this is the output program:

```
is_greater_than(A,B) :- 
    A>B. 
is_an_animal(A) :- 
    member(A,["dog","cat"]).
```

This translator is only a proof-of-concept, but it may still make it easier to convert some simple PHP programs into Prolog.