# How to combine PHP and Prolog

Tags: php, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to call Prolog using a PHP script. I'm using the syntax I found [here](http://www.j-paine.org/dobbs/prolog_from_php.html), which is:

```
$cmd = "nice -n15 /software/bin/pl -f /home/popx/cgi-bin/test.pl -g test,halt";
```

The program `/bin/pl` is where I have Prolog installed, and `/home/popx/cgi-bin/test.pl` is the location of the file to be consulted. After changing the paths accordingly, I get no output. Can someone help me, and give me some pointers?

I'm already conversant with the questions [How to use Prolog with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298723/how-to-use-prolog-with-php), and
[Invoking SWI-Prolog from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056659/invoking-swi-prolog-from-php), but they do not answer my question.

Comment: Please show the PHP code that uses `$cmd`.

Comment: <? $cmd = "nice -n15 plwin.exe -L128k -G128k -T128k -A128k -f test.pl -g test,halt";?>   <? system( $cmd );?>  Is the PHP code syntactically correct?

Comment: @user590264: Run `php -l yourfile.php` to check the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve the output with `system()`. Use `exec()` instead.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php